# WSO2 Identity Server: update user fails

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to update a user i created.

It says *Error while updating attributes of user: vaisakh@abcd.com*

I've followed these steps before https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/

I'm getting this error message in the terminal

[image]

####################################################################

see full logs

```
[2022-03-11 17:39:56,222] []  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2022-03-11 17:39:56,222] []  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Waiting for required OSGi Service: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskEngineService
[2022-03-11 17:40:02,418] [555cdc99-ed81-4cdd-8882-6aeab3cda308] ERROR {org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint} - Internal Server Error while updating User org.wso2.charon.core.exceptions.CharonException: Error while updating attributes of user: vaisakh@abcd.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.updateUser(SCIMUserManager.java:570)
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.updateWithPUT(UserResourceEndpoint.java:546)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserResource.updateUser(UserResource.java:268)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:232)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : vaisakh@abcd.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4404)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.updateUser(SCIMUserManager.java:554)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:196)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:199)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : vaisakh@abcd.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.handleException(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2354)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doDeleteUserClaimValueWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1331)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4463)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for MessageType : MODIFY_REQUEST
Message ID : 4
    Modify Request
        Object : 'mail=vaisakh@abcd.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
            Modification[0]
                Operation :  delete
                Modification
mail: (null)org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@f4256b2a    ManageDsaITImpl Control
        Type OID    : '2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2'
        Criticality : 'false'
'
: ERR_62 Entry mail=vaisakh@abcd.com,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org does not have the mail attributeType, which is part of the RDN";]; remaining name 'mail=vaisakh@abcd.com'
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3186)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3101)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2892)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1408)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:167)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doDeleteUserClaimValueWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1328)
    ... 75 more

[2022-03-11 17:40:27,097] []  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2022-03-11 17:40:27,119] []  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Waiting for required OSGi Service: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskEngineService
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach the error trace printed on terminal?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I've added the logs

Comment: you have tried the scimv1 URL. Do you get the same result if scim v2 endpoint is used? `https://localhsot:9443/scim2/Users/{user-id}`

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathnaYes i get the same error message for scim v2 also

Answer (score 0):

When we configure the email address as the username, we are using the email claim value as the username. In the request body, what you have passed as the emails are the home email claim and the work email claim. We need to pass the single string which maps to the local email claim as well.

Sample payload:

```
{
    "schemas": [],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "gunasinghe",
        "givenName": "hasinitg"
    },
    "userName": "vaisakh@abcd.com",
    "emails": [
        "vaisakh@abcd.com",
        {
            "primary": true,
            "value": "hasini_home.com",
            "type": "home"
        },
        {
            "value": "hasini_work.com",
            "type": "work"
        }
    ]
}
```